# Spark arraytype issue

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

In the kafka data that comes for me to process(json)

Yes raw data is converted from xml to json If the object in xml is single, it comes as a single ({}), but if the object comes more than once, it comes as an array ([])

JSON EXAMPLE

```
{"name":"b","surname":"b","adress":{"city":"d","street":"e"}}
```

```
{"name":"b","surname":"c","adress":[{"city":"d","street":"e"}],[{"city":"f","street":"g"}]}
```

SPARK EXAMPLE

```scala
private val schema = new StructType().add("a", ArrayType(adresschema),true)

adresschema = new StructType().add("city", String,true).add("street", String,true)

val df = spark.read.schema(schema)
```

but Cannot parse spark for a single element how can I do it ?

i need normalize write data

| name | surname | adress.city | adress.street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | b | d | e |
| b | c | d | e |
| b | c | f | g |

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. What is your input data (show us the raw data you're trying to read)? What code are you using? What result are you getting and what do you expected instead?

Comment: Sounds like you're having some JSON data that sometimes is an array, and sometimes is an object, and you'd like to handle both somehow?

Comment: Yes raw data is converted from xml to json If the object in xml is single, it comes as a single ({}), but if the object comes more than once, it comes as an array ([]).  example raw data                                                 
             {"name":"b","surname":"c","adress":{"city":"d","street":"e"}}
              {"name":"b","surname":"c","adress":[{"city":"d","street":"e"}],[{"city":"f","street":"g"}]}